# unable to map node.js app to port 80 using haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

I have a node js app running on port 5000 on my ubuntu server.I can currently access it at http://206.189.22.155:5000/employeeList. Now I want to map this to port 80 using haproxy so that I can access it directly at http://206.189.22.155/employeeList.

What I have tried so far (haproxy.cfg)

```
frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind *:80

    acl path-page-designer              path_beg -i /employeeList    
    use_backend page-designer-backend   if path-page-designer

backend page-designer-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    http-request set-path /employeeList

    server  appserver1 206.189.22.155:5000
```

With the above configuration, I am getting a  "503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request" error upon hitting the URL http://206.189.22.155/employeeList. What changes has to be made in order to map it to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your config. I replaced your backend entry "206.189.22.155:5000" with the homepage of a german IT news site ("193.99.144.80:80") and accesses to "/employeeList" worked fine.

Remember that haproxy does a http validation if in mode http. You backend needs to reply with valid http on access (at the moment it responds with an empty reply) or haproxy will show an error.

Comment: Now do you know how i can dynamically map the port for all the application in haproxy using some sort of generic script?

Comment: Dynamic configuration in HAProxy either involves generating the config or using the Socket API to configure HAProxy while running. But this is really too complex to solve it in the comment section, maybe open a new question with a description what you want to achieve. ;-)